# How to parse this JSON on Android

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON response as follows

```
{
    'data': {
        'error': 0,
        'results': {
            'color': 'Mostly red gray.',
            'labels': 'Diet Coke',
        }
    }
}
```

How to parse it to get labels value? Thank you so much.

Comment: Which JSON processing library are you using?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I am using org.json.JSONObject

Comment: No problem, have posted a solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Using `org.json.JSONObject` you can use something like:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json); // String 'json' contains your raw JSON
String labels = obj.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("results").getString("labels"); // "Diet Coke"
```

Comment: I try obj.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("results").getString("labels") and it works great. Again, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the link might be of your help http://androidosbeginning.blogspot.com/2010/11/json-parsing-example.html